# How does ord() convert bytes to int

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, byte, pyserial

I'm using PySerial and trying to receive a byte array {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11} sent from a MCU. Here's the array I get from PySerial

```
b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b
```

By looking at the first few "elements" (and the last one as well), I first thought they are just hex numbers until I saw 't' and 'n'.

So I tried to see the output of `ord(b'\t')` and it indeed gives me the int number 9. I'm a bit confused since `ord()` is supposed to return the unicode.

Why is 9 represented as b'\t' and 10 as b'\n'? What is this representation and can I find like a conversion table anywhere?

Thank you!

Comment: Byte values that correspond to characters with escape sequences are shown as the escape sequence. Since the ASCII code of `\t` is 9, `\x09` is shown as `\t`.

Comment: bytes objects use the ascii readable characters to represent the corresponding bytes.

Comment: If you want to view a `bytes` object as its numeric values, use `list()`, e.g. `s = b'\x01\x02\t'; `print(list(s))` gives `[1, 2, 9]`.

Comment: @Barmar Got it. Thanks!

Comment: [ASCII character codes](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: `\t` is the escape sequence for Horizontal Tab.

Comment: This is useful, thanks! @MarkTolonen